# How to extract data of previous week based on drop down from the Yahoo Fantasy Football

Tags: google-sheets, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

Hy, I am using Yahoo Fantasy Football and I have design Google Sheet to get the score data which is the working fine. The link to the sheet is as under.

[Google Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f2X4ZtNmHI7r46yrfo_5lUcYJe0yonV9r8QV43A8qKY/edit?usp=sharing)

I have changed the permission to Editor. I have made a drop-down which holds the information of Week numbers. Basically, my idea is that by choosing the week number I want to populate the data from yahoo fantasy football. For importing data, i am using this command.

```
=importhtml("https://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/683375","table",1)
```

and this command is working well.
I tried it by using the same command but it does not works for the week numbers. The source of the page is as under.

[image]

so according to the given picture, here is the week number, I want to implement the same in the google sheet by using the dropdown. I have implemented the drop down but it does not work. Is there a way to interlink both using scripts or command so from google sheet when I chose week from the drop-down the concerning data should be populated? please take a look at the Google Sheet given above. I am also getting this error, while it was working fine before, how can it be resolved also.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Is there any suggestion or solution please?

Comment: Hi ! So the data you want to get depending on the the week dropdown you are selecting is the table under **Matchups** that you can select by week right? Not the one under standings right?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) cannot retrieve elements dynamically inserted by a script. In your case the content on `Week matchups` is inserted dynamically and therefore will not be retrieved (it will return empty). Moreover, `IMPORTHTML` olny gets data from tables or lists and if you inspect what it seemed to be a table in `Week Matchup` is just actually a series of `div`s. If the content would not be inserted dynamically, to get the data from these `div`s you would need to use [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342).

If you still want to retrieve this information I am afraid that you will need to look for other web scraping techniques.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you are saying. Now I have decided to work with API.